# php-fpm & nginx & Linux хочу создать общий файл конфигурации как на продакшен так и на локальный дев станцию

Tags: php, linux, nginx, php-fpm

1. И так смотрите очень хочется создать некий файл конфига для папок с сайтами которые поднимаются как на машине дев, так и на машине прод. Идея такая. Проект подразумевает из себя то что на локальной машине на разных портах будет поднято разные проекты.(В дальнейшем возможно не только пыха а что что ещё может быть) А на продакшене на разных под доменных именах (Или тоже на разных портах данные момент еще обсуждается)будут подняты разные проекты. Важный нюанс. Проект подразумевает то что он должен быть сквозным по версии пчп а именно в некоторых папках должны быть проэкты допустим на 5 пчп а где-то на 8 версии и контроль этих версий по идеи лучше отдать на нджнкс что бы на каждый проект мог взять определённую версию пчп и уже от этого отталкиваться.
   Кстати, интересует вопрос как себя нджнкс ведёт с другими языками си шарп, джава, пайтон, си++ Так есть подозрения что придётся поднимать веб проекты на этих языках но контроль над ними делегировать нджинкс. если кто-то знает по этому вопросу то прошу написать..
2. Что Я сделал...
   Пока что установлены 3 версии пыхи
   php 5.6 / php 7.4 / php 8.1
   Да у меня есть как обычный пчп так и фпм
   Что говорит альтернатива

   $update-alternatives --config php
   Есть 3 варианта для альтернативы php (предоставляет /usr/bin/php).

   Выбор   Путь         Приор Состояние

   ---

   0            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        автоматический режим

   - 1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        ручной режим
     2            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        ручной режим
     3            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        ручной режим

   Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

Вот
Обычная пыха есть, но точно ли фпм есть?
Конечно

```
$ pwd
/run/php
$ls
php5.6-fpm.pid   php7.4-fpm.pid   php8.1-fpm.pid   php-fpm.sock
php5.6-fpm.sock  php7.4-fpm.sock  php8.1-fpm.sock
```

Это хорошо? Наверное.. Я точно знаю что они установлены и та и та... Что по факту облегчает мне работу. Но возникает другой вопрос пробовал ли Я проверить они как процесы запущены?

```
$ps aux | grep php-fpm
root        1122  0.0  0.1 151384 18136 ?        Ss   ноя03   0:33 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root        1124  0.0  0.0 221604 15576 ?        Ss   ноя03   0:33 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root        1128  0.0  0.0 224932 16180 ?        Ss   ноя03   0:33 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
```

Предполагаю да..

А что насчёт апача???

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     

> Active: active (running)

 since Thu 2022-11-03 10:22:39 MSK; 6 days ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 284906 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1342 (apache2)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 18959)
     Memory: 18.1M
        CPU: 28.602s
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─  1342 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─284943 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─284944 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─284946 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─284947 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─284948 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

ноя 06 00:00:03 user systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
ноя 07 00:00:03 user systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server...
ноя 07 00:00:03 user apachectl[166482]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain n>
ноя 07 00:00:03 user systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
ноя 08 00:00:02 user systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server...
ноя 08 00:00:02 user apachectl[222111]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain n>
lines 1-23
```

Да работает...  Если работает пчп, если работает апач, и как бы все и всем довольны. может ошибка в нджиныксе?
Его конфиг

```
# настройка для тестового окружения
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

#   ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

#   sendfile on;
#   tcp_nopush on;
#   types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

#   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
#   default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

#   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    #???????
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; 
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k; 
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 90;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 90;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 90;
    #???
    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
#CRM server
server {

         listen       81;
         server_name  localhost;
         root         /var/www/crm/crm/web;

         access_log /var/log/nginx/example.journaldev.com-access.log;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.journaldev.com-error.log error;
         index index.html index.htm index.php;

         location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         }

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock;
#       listen.owner = www-data;
#                listen.group = www-data;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
#LK server
server {

         listen       82;
         #listen.owner = www-data; #?
     #listen.group = www-data; #?
         server_name  localhost;
         root         /var/www/lk/lk/web;

         access_log /var/log/nginx/example.journaldev.com-access.log;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.journaldev.com-error.log error;
         index index.html index.htm index.php;

         location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         }

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock;
#             listen.owner = www-data;
#             listen.group = www-data;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
#test server
server {

         listen       90;
         server_name  example.journaldev.com;
         root         /var/www/ltestWork;

         access_log /var/log/nginx/example.journaldev.com-access.log;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.journaldev.com-error.log error;
         index index.html index.htm index.php;

         location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         }

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock;
#             listen.owner = www-data;
#             listen.group = www-data;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
##End Lk
#   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Как видно нечего не затейливого нет, однако всеравно ошибка 502. Проэкты в папках есть, файлы индекса тоже.. Но почему-то в сумме всё это не работает. Кто знает прошу подсказать. И да забыл сказать что нджныкс Я пере запускал и не раз после изменений как версий пчп так и имения пути в папки  и т.д. То есть ошибка 502 Врятли из-за того что нджинкс не пере запущен и изменения не вступили в силу

Comment: Причем тут `apache` и `php-fpm`? Смотрите логи `php-fpm` и `nginx. По коду ошибки в браузере никто никогда не гадает!